# Azure Static Web app with custom Azure AD Tenant not redirecting

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to setup in a way where I only want my internal azure AD users be able to see the pages deployed for Azure static web app. The app works fine when I just use default aad (i.e. can login from any azure AD user) and users are getting redirected to Login for Azure AD.

The issue is when I add azure ad auth for my tenant to my staticwebapp.config.json as per doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad) the authentication is not working and users are not getting redirected to Azure AD for authentication instead users stays on same site and showing 404  for /.auth/login/aad page. I am not able to figure out why its redirecting fine without the auth section in the config.json file and not with the auth section for custom Azure Ad authentication.

```
"auth": {
"identityProviders": {
  "azureActiveDirectory": {
    "registration": {
      "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/v2.0",
      "clientIdSettingName": "AAD_CLIENT_ID",
      "clientSecretSettingName": "AAD_CLIENT_SECRET"
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Error: when you trying to navigate to web app getting error (404)**

Add the `AADClientID` and `AADSecret` to the web app configuration.

**1)**  Go to your Static Web App, click on **Configuration** and choose **+ Add**:

[image]

**2)**   Add the two entries, one with the name **`AADSecret`**  and  **`AADClientID`** with the client ID

[image]

**3)**  click on the **Save**, you will be prompted for authentication and the first time you authenticate the app you will get a **Permissions requested** dialog since we are allowing the app to sign in and read profile information.

[image]

For more details refer this [document](http://jsandersblog.azurewebsites.net/2021/07/02/walkthrough-static-web-apps-and-aad-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to get it working by specifying values in the application settings. Do you know how will this work for stage site (on Pull request create). Stage sites creates the environment and url dynamically.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Are `AADSecret` and `AADClientId` still the required names or is it `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` as outlined in this recent Microsoft tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad%2Cinvitations#configure-a-custom-identity-provider

Comment: names don't matter, they just need to match. so using `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` are perfectly fine as per docs. Just ensure that the Configuration matches the variable names in `staticwebapp.config.json`